# awk how to set record separator as multiple consecutive empty lines or lines only include space and/or tab characters?

Tags: regex, awk

I know I can use `RS=""` to set record separator as multiple consecutive empty lines. However if those lines contain space or tab characters it will not work. I'm thinking to set `RF` as some kind of regular expression to do the match. But it's hard, since in this case often `\n` will be used as the field separator `FS`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
awk '!NF {$0=""}1' file | awk -v RS="" '{print NR,$0}'
```

The first `awk` counts the fields on the line.  This will be `0` if you have blank lines or lines with spaces and tabs only.  Then it just change the line to nothing.  After this you can use the `RS=""`

---

Here is a  `gnu awk` version (due to multiple characters in RS):

```
awk -v RS="\n([[:space:]]*\n)+" '{print NR,$0}' file
```

It may work without parentheses, but I am not sure if all will be covered then:

```
awk -v RS="\n[[:space:]]*\n+" '{print NR,$0}' file
```

Comment: To clarify what Jotne alludes to in the answer: according to the awk standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06), "If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified".  Using multiple character in RS requires that a specific version of awk be used, and the usage here works with `gawk`.

Comment: Thanks Jotne! Actually I'm using the default awk on Mac and can't make it work. After installed gawk by `brew install gawk` I can use the command to get what I want (based on your version): `gawk 'BEGIN {RS = "\n(( |\t)*\n)+"; FS = "\n"} {print $2}' multiaddress.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='\n(([[:space:]]*\n)+|$)' '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}' file
```

e.g.

```
$ awk '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}' file
1 <a>
2 <  b>
3 <   >
4 < c>

$ awk -v RS='\n(([[:space:]]*\n)+|$)' '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}' file
1 <a
  b>
2 < c>
```

Comment: Thanks Ed for the help!